# How to update data in cloudant using nodejs cloudant module?

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb, cloudant

Below mentioned sample json documents.It contains two fields.

```
{
  "_id": "daef4a0e39c0c7a00feb721f6c4ce8b9",

  "_rev": "2-8c7ef28df59ecbdaa23b536e58691416",

  "name": "sukil",

  "skills": "java"
}


In server.js

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var cloudant = require('cloudant');

cloudant({account:"test", password:"test"}, function(err, cloudant) {

var alice = cloudant.use('opti-update')
alice.atomic("_design/sample", "inplace", "daef4a0e39c0c7a00feb721f6c4ce8b9", {field: "name", value: "bar"}, function (error, response) {
 console.log(error+""+response);
})
})
```

Here _design/sample is a design document name and inplace is update function name then next is document id.It returns error is document update conflict and response is undefined.

```
In design document mentioned below

{
  "_id": "_design/sample",

  "_rev": "9-94393ee4665bdfd6fb283e3419a53f24",

  "updates": {

    "inplace": "function(doc,req){var field = req.body.field;var value = req.body.value;doc[field] = value;return [doc,''];}"

  }
}


I want to update the data in cloudant using node cloudant module. I want to update the name field in json document.Above method i tried but it shows document update conflict error.How to resolve this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The atomic method assumes the first parameter as the design document only. So need to explicitly specify `"_design"`.

```
alice.atomic("sample", "inplace", "daef4a0e39c0c7a00feb721f6c4ce8b9", {field: "name", value: "bar"}, function (error, response) {
 console.log(error+""+response);
})
```

This may be causing the problem.